# NavBar jQuery mobile: no right positioning

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, navbar

I am setting up a jQuery mobile webpage. We set up a NavBar in the header.

The problem that occurs right now is that the navbar is padding (I guess) 1px to the right.

So on Mobile screens the navbar is lining out to the right and does not fit perfectly under the header bar..

The links o you could see what i Mean: http://lc.gorillaspots.nl/test/l/web/test/test.php

For example I put the Navbar as a stand alone in the Page (under the header navbar) and then you can see it had 1px on the right missing..

WI can't seem to find the problem in stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an another css file and if it is below jquery mobile css file add this to it:

```
.ui-navbar li .ui-btn {
    margin: 0 -1px !important;
}
```

Original style is attached to a tag (div[data-role="navbar"] ul li a)